# $L^p$ convergence of infinitesimal generator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

I have trouble express explicitly the following
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+} h^{-1}\|f_h-f-hg\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}=0.
$$
which relates to the earlier post in finding generator.

[How to find the infinitesimal generator of this semigroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617669/how-to-find-the-infinitesimal-generator-of-this-semigroup?rq=1)

Could anyone help writing out the integral?

For the $L^p$ part, I think the following theorem from Hewitt and Stromberg can be viewed as a proof?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the translation semigroup (actually, it's a group because you're working on $\mathbb{R}$ and not $[0,\infty)$.) There are various ways of dealing with this problem directly. For example, to show that it is a $C^0$ group, it is enough to show contuity of $T(t)f$ for $f$ in a dense subspace $\mathcal{M}$ of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, such as the subspace $\mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of compactly-supported infinitely-differentiable functions. Then, because $\|T(t)f\|=\|f\|$ for all $t$, a simple three $\epsilon$ argument extends the continuity result to all $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Or, because this group is related to the Fourier transform, you can Fourier transform instead
$$
            \mathcal{F}(T(t)f) = \mathcal{F}(f(\cdot+t))=e^{its}\hat{f}(s).
$$
The Fourier transform turns translation into multiplication by an exponential. From this you immediately obtain the $C^0$ property from the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem and the Plancherel Theorem:
$$
         \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\|T(t)f-f\|^2=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|1-e^{its}||\hat{f}(s)|^{2}ds = 0
$$
It is known that $s\hat{f}(s) \in L^2$ iff $f$ is absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f' \in L^{2}$. For any such $f$, the dominated convergence theorem also gives
$$
        \lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|\frac{1}{t}(T(t)-I)f-f'\| \\
        =\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|\frac{e^{ist}-1}{t}\hat{f}(s)-is\hat{f}(s)\| \\
        = \lim_{t\downarrow 0}\|\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}(e^{isu}-1)du(is\hat{f}(s))\| = 0.
$$
It's a little trickier, but $f$ is in the domain of the generator iff $s\hat{f}(s) \in L^2$.

**Added to deal with $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $1 \le p < \infty$:** The translation group is continuous on every such $L^p$ space, but not on $L^{\infty}$. As mentioned in the first paragraph, the $C^0$ property can be proved by approximating $f\in L^p$ by $g \in \mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
     \|T(t+h)f-T(t)f\|_p  \\
   \le \|T(t+h)(f-g)\|_p+\|T(t+h)g-T(t)g\|_p+\|T(t)(g-f)\|_p \\
   \le 2\|f-g\|_p+\|T(t+h)g-T(t)g\|_p.
$$
Because $g(x+t+h)-g(x+t) \rightarrow 0$ for all $x+t$ as $h\downarrow 0$, then dominated convergence gives
$$
          \limsup_{h\downarrow 0}\|T(t+h)f-T(t)f\|_p \le 2\|f-g\|_p,\;\;\; g \in \mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Because the above holds for all such $g$, then
$$
   \limsup_{h\downarrow 0}\|T(t+h)f-T(t)f\|_p \le \inf_{g\in\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}}2\|f-g\|_p = 0.
$$
So the $C^0$ property of $T$ holds on $L^p$ for $1 \le p < \infty$.

Now suppose that $f\in\mathcal{D}(A)$, where $A_p$ is the generator of $T$ on $L^p$. Then, by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem,
\begin{align}
  \int_{a}^{b}A_pf\,dt
  & = \lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{a}^{b}(T(h)-I)f\,dt  \\
  & = \lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{a}^{b}f(t+h)-f(t)\,dt \\
  & = \lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\left[\int_{b}^{b+h}f(t)dt-\int_{a}^{a+h}f(t)dt\right] \\
  & = f(b)-f(a) \mbox{ (a.e.  a, b)}
\end{align}
It follows that $f$ can be redefined to be continuous by changing $f$, if necessary, on set of $0$ measure. After doing so,
$$
       f(b)-f(a) = \int_{a}^{b}A_p f\,dt.
$$
Therefore, $f$ becomes absolutely continuous with
$$
                f'(x) = (A_p f)(x),\;\;\; x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
The converse is similarly proved: If $f$ is absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f' \in L^p$, then $f \in \mathcal{D}(A_p)$ and $A_pf = f'$.

Comment: actually, I think a theorem from Hewitt and Stromberg p.199 proves the $L^p$ part, would be great if you let me know what you think...see edited question.

Comment: @math101 : The proof is identical to mine. Essentially all such proofs have to be. The continuity property is simple for compactly supported $C^{\infty}$ functions, and that's enough because such functions are dense in $L^p$, which is proved using a 3$\epsilon$ argument to approximate.

Comment: where in the original question of the earlier post says $g\in C_c^{\infty}$?

Comment: Also, why is $\int_a^b [T(h)f](t)\,dt=\int_a^b f(t+h) dt$? the first two lines after Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: I see, that equality holds only when $A$ is $d/dt$, if I have $d^2/d x^2$, what would be changed?

Comment: @math101 : 1. I have $\mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}$ in what I added from $L^p$ because of your request to work in $L^p$ and avoid Fourier transform on $L^2$. 2. $(T(h)f)=f(t+h)$ is the definition of $T(h)$. 3. $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ has an associated semigroup that is not translation.

Comment: Also, your $g$ is the same as in the original post, right?

Comment: In the case of associated semigroup, I believe I should still have $\lim_{t\to 0}|T(t)f-f|_p=0$ holds, but I am not sure what what happen to those steps after " by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem..."

Comment: Have you shown 1) $Af$ exists and 2) $Af\in L^p$ for all $f\in L^p$? I have problem on your last sentence What is the original of the "converse"?

Comment: @math101 : I showed you how, if $Af$ exists, then $f$ is absolutely continuous with $f' \in L^p$ and, in that case, $Af=f'$. How you tried to do the converse?

Comment: I was wondering, when showing the $L^p$ case, why don't you just make some changes of that 3 lines you had for $L^2$, I mean, apply DCT to the ration by looking at the boundedness of $T(t)f-f$ in $L^p$ and the boundedness in $t$?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31632/discussion-on-answer-by-trialanderror-lp-convergence-of-infinitesimal-generat). I left the messages from the last 24 hours and deleted the rest. You can find them in that chat, if you need to recall them.