# Example 4.8 ; functional analysis book by S.kesavan

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, adjoint-operators, semigroup-of-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $V=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and let ${s(t)}$ be the semigroup defined by $(s(t)f)(s)=f(s +t)$. Find its infinitesimal generator $A$.

Comment: Please format posts in MathJax.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617669/how-to-find-the-infinitesimal-generator-of-this-semigroup